# Use Inclusion-Exclusion to find the number of arrangements of 4 A's, 5 B's, 6 C's, 7 D's , 8 E's with exactly 2 adjacent C's

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I found the number of arrangements in the problem stated above by arranging the letters other than C and then counting the number of ways to insert the C's into the gaps, giving an answer of

$\displaystyle\hspace{1.2 in}\frac{24!}{4!5!7!8!}\binom{25}{5}\binom{5}{1}=281625478590456000$,

but I would like to find out how to work this problem using Inclusion-Exclusion instead.

Comment: @user49640 I tried this out, but I think it gives an answer of about $4.65\times 10^{17}$ if I calculated everything correctly.

Comment: @user49460  Thanks for your comment, and for looking at this again.  (I'm not quite sure why this idea doesn't work.)

Comment: My idea didn't work because other C's could have been adjacent, besides the F. Your approach is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the number of arrangements with exactly one pair of C's, we must use a generalization of the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.  Let $A_k$ denote the set of arrangements with $k$ pairs of adjacent C's.

*One pair of adjacent C's*

We have $29$ objects to arrange: $4$ A's, $5$ B's, $1$ CC, $4$ C's, $7$ D's, $8$ E's.  They can be arranged in 
$$|A_1| = \frac{29!}{4!5!1!4!7!8!}$$
distinguishable ways.

*Two pairs of adjacent C's*

Two disjoint pairs of C's:  We have $28$ objects to arrange:  $4$ A's, $5$ B's, $2$ CC's, $2$ C's, $7$ D's, $8$ E's.  They can be arranged in 
$$\frac{28!}{4!5!2!2!7!8!}$$
distinguishable ways.

Two overlapping pairs of C's:  We have $28$ objects to arrange:  $4$ A's, $5$ B's, $1$ CCC, $3$ C's, $7$ D's, $8$ E's.  They can be arranged in
$$\frac{28!}{4!5!1!3!7!8!}$$
distinguishable ways.

Hence, 
$$|A_2| = \frac{28!}{4!5!2!2!7!8!} + \frac{28!}{4!5!1!3!7!8!}$$

*Three pairs of adjacent C's*

Three disjoint pairs of adjacent C's:  We have $27$ objects to arrange:  $4$ A's, $5$ B's, $3$ CC's, $7$ D's, $8$ E's.  They can be arranged in 
$$\frac{27!}{4!5!3!7!8!}$$
distinguishable ways.

One pair of adjacent C's and two overlapping pairs of adjacent C's:  We have $27$ objects to arrange:  $4$ A's, $5$ B's, $1$ CC, $1$ CCC, $1$ C, $7$ D's, $8$ E's.  They can be arranged in 
$$\frac{27!}{4!5!1!1!1!7!8!}$$
distinguishable ways.

Three overlapping pairs of adjacent C's:  We have $27$ objects to arrange:  $4$ A's, $5$ B's, $1$ CCCC, $2$ C's, $7$ D's, $8$ E's.  They can be arranged in 
$$\frac{27!}{4!5!1!2!7!8!}$$
distinguishable ways.

Hence, 
$$|A_3| = \frac{27!}{4!5!3!7!8!} + \frac{27!}{4!5!1!1!1!7!8!} + \frac{27!}{4!5!1!2!7!8!}$$

*Four pairs of adjacent C's*

Two sets of two overlapping pairs of adjacent C's:  We have $26$ objects to arrange: $4$ A's, $5$ B's, $2$ CCC's, $7$ D's, $8$ E's.  They can be arranged in 
$$\frac{26!}{4!5!2!7!8!}$$
distinguishable ways.

One pair of adjacent C's and three overlapping pairs of adjacent C's:  We have $26$ objects to arrange:  $4$ A's, $5$ B's, $1$ CC, $1$ CCCC, $7$ D's, $8$ E's.  They can be arranged in 
$$\frac{26!}{4!5!1!1!7!8!}$$
distinguishable ways.

Four overlapping pairs of adjacent C's:  We have $26$ objects to arrange:  $4$ A's, $5$ B's, $1$ CCCCC, $1$ C, $7$ D's, $8$ E's.  They can be arranged in 
$$\frac{26!}{4!5!1!1!7!8!}$$
distinguishable ways.

Hence,
$$|A_4| = \frac{26!}{4!5!2!7!8!} + \frac{26!}{4!5!1!1!7!8!} + \frac{26!}{4!5!1!1!7!8!}$$

*Five pairs of adjacent C's*

We have $25$ objects to arrange:  $4$ A's, $5$ B's, $1$ CCCCCC, $7$ D's, $8$ E's.  They can be arranged in 
$$|A_5| = \frac{25!}{4!5!1!7!8!}$$
distinguishable ways.

Let $|B_k|$ denote the number of arrangements with at least $k$ pairs of adjacent C's.

*Number of arrangements with at least one pair of adjacent C's*
$$|B_1| = |A_1| - |A_2| + |A_3| - |A_4| + |A_5|$$

*Number of arrangements with at least two pairs of adjacent C's*
$$|B_2| = |A_2| - |A_3| + |A_4| - |A_5|$$

*Number of arrangements with at least three pairs of adjacent C's*
$$|B_3| = |A_3| - |A_4| + |A_5|$$

*Number of arrangements with at least four pairs of adjacent C's*
$$|B_4| = |A_4| - |A_5|$$

*Number of arrangements with five pairs of adjacent C's*
$$|B_5| = |A_5|$$

The number of arrangements with exactly one pair of adjacent C's is 
\begin{align*}
|B_1| & - |B_2| + |B_3| - |B_4| + |B_5|\\ 
& = (|A_1| - |A_2| + |A_3| - |A_4| + |A_5|) - (|A_2| - |A_3| + |A_4| - |A_5|) + (|A_3| - |A_4| + |A_5|) - (|A_4| - |A_5|) + |A_5|\\
& = |A_1| - 2|A_2| + 3|A_3| - 4|A_4| + 5|A_5|\\
& = 281625478590456000
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your answer -- you explained it very clearly!

Comment: @MontyHall  Of course, your method is much more efficient.

Comment: Should the description of $A_k$ be changed somewhat? (Otherwise it would seem that $|A_1|$ would give the desired answer.)

Comment: The set $A_1$ denotes an arrangement with one pair of adjacent C's.  It does preclude the possibility that there is more than one pair of adjacent C's within the arrangement.   Since arrangements with two pairs of adjacent C's are counted twice by $|A_1|$, arrangements with three pairs of adjacent C's are counted three times by $|A_1|$, and so forth, the number $|A_1|$ over counts arrangements with at least one pair of adjacent C's. The number $|A_1| - |A_2| + |A_3| - |A_4| + |A_5|$ tells us how many arrangements have at least one pair of adjacent C's.

Answer (score 1):

4A,5B,1 Pair of C, 4C, 7D, 8E

$A1=\frac{29!}{4!*5!*7!*8!*4!.2}$

4A,5B,2 Pair of C, 2C, 7D, 8E

$A2=\frac{28!}{4!*5!*7!*8!*2!*2!.4}$

4A,5B,3 Pair of C, 7D, 8E

$A3=\frac{27!}{4!*5!*7!*8!*3!.8}$

4A,5B,1 Pair of C,1 triplet of C, 1C, 7D, 8E

$A4=\frac{27!}{4!*5!*7!*8!*3!*2}$

4A,5B,1 Pair of C,1 quadrapulet of C, 7D, 8E

$A5=\frac{26!}{4!*5!*7!*8!*4!.2}$

Using Principle of Exclusion and INclusion:

$A = A1-A2+A3-A4+A5=2.81034E+17$

Comment: This answer appears to be too large, if I did the calculations correctly.

Comment: I agree with your calculation, but I believe the correct answer, as given in the problem above,  is about $2.8\times 10^{17}$.

Comment: I take back my statement,  the answer is 2.8257E+17, I am sorry

Comment: I don't think I understand the last number you have in the denominator for each of A1, A2, and A3.

Comment: For each pair, you will have to divide by 2, In A1, you have one pair, In A2 you have two pairs, and In A3 you have three pairs.  I forgot about taking care of that

Comment: Thank you for explaining this.  This answer still seems too large, though, by more than $10^{15}$.

Comment: What are you comparing it with, a textbook answer? or that of yours

Comment: Be careful.  The sequence CCC contains of two pairs of C's.  Similarly, the sequence CCCC contains three pairs of C's.  Consequently, you can have up to five pairs of C's.

Comment: I just took care of it.  Fixed

Comment: This answer appears to be too small by about $6.2\times10^{14}$.

Comment: What you attempted to calculate is the number of arrangements with at least one pair of adjacent C's.  We need to calculate the number of arrangements with exactly one pair of adjacent C's, which requires a generalization of the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.